How to Animate an Icon or Draw a Polyline for Route Tracking in a React Native App Using OpenRouteService
I am working on an on-demand taxi mobile app using React Native. The app is for academic purposes and includes a feature for tracking the driver's route.
Problem Statement:
I need to implement a feature where either an icon moves along a map to represent the driver's location in real-time(or as a simulation) as they pick up and transport a client, or a polyline is drawn to show the route to the destination. I'm using OpenRouteService for routing.
After the driver leaves the client to his destination, the trip should be stored in my database (firestore/firebase)
Can anyone guide me on how to proceed ?
What I've Tried:
I've looked into using the MapView component from react-native-maps for displaying the map.
Attempted to integrate OpenRouteService API for route data but unsure how to animate the icon or draw the route dynamically.
I expect to see a moving icon or a drawing polyline updating in real-time on the map, but I'm stuck on how to implement the animation or polyline drawing in React Native.
